# jQuery stop event from happening

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery Nestable http://dbushell.github.io/Nestable/ and have converted all of the items into a text box so they can be updated, now the problem is that when you click on the item it starts to move them and will not let you select the textbox.

To combat this I have used the below

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

However this only works on the first item, is there any way to get it to work for all items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

This should help you.

From comments, I think this is what you are needing:

```
$('input[type=text]').mousedown(function(){
event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this stops just the single text box from working so now nothing allows a textbox to be clicked this is the full code that is being used;

`$("#page_tab_title").on("mousedown", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
 });`

Comment: Provide me a jsfiddle and I'll help you easily

Comment: I have got it working http://jsfiddle.net/V22A4/ but this stops all of the click and drag, is there any way of limiting this to the input txt box?